# Reducing time in the following code

Tags: c++, performance

I gave this solution at the codechef for the problem code : FCTRL.

I saw the compile time of others people using the same the language c ( i am using c++ gcc 4.8.1) is somewhat less,
mine is 0.46s while their is 0.23

Can somebody help me in reducing the time if possible?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long int t,i,temp;
    cin>>t;
    long int n[t],a[t];
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        temp=1;
        a[i]=0;
        cin>>n[i];
        while(temp)
        {
            temp=n[i]/5;
            a[i]+=temp;
            n[i]=n[i]/5;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    cout<<a[i]<<"\n";

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with codechef, why does the compile time matter?

Comment: it's not that it matters but i wanted to just know if i can reduce the time of execution of this program.

Comment: And also if i am using more variables than required and stuff like that.

Comment: Time of execution is a different thing than compilation time. What problem should your program solve?

Comment: I think the problem and several solutions are at http://www.codechef.com/problems/FCTRL

Comment: Goodness, I looked at the [first solution](http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/676122) and while it may be mathematically clever, C++ wise it's ugly. The guy probably never heard of stack allocation (`Reader *RC=new Reader(1100000);`) or `std::vector`... *sigh*.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, as you are using c++ and they are using c, it might be due to how the compiler handles each instruction.

Also you may try replacing

```
temp=n[i]/5;
a[i]+=temp;
n[i]=n[i]/5;
```

By

```
temp=n[i]/5;
a[i]+=temp;
n[i]=temp;    //why compute the value again
```

And see if some time reduces or not

Comment: Interesting, I would expect the compiler to optimize this (Common Sub-Expression Elimination), however I wonder if there could be a potential aliasing issue: if the compiler cannot prove that `a[i]` and `n[i]` are distinct, then it cannot eliminate the sub-expression and thus your optimization may matter.

Comment: So, turns out that just using scanf and printf reduced the time to 0.2 seconds.Thank you.

Comment: @LakshayChhikara and also you might consider using `getchar_ignore()` and other input options like this which skips setting and releasing of mutexes if you are coding for single threaded applications.

Answer (score 0):

You worst offense to C++ is using Variadic-Length arrays, those are non-standards.

And in fact, it turns out you absolutely do not need them. This problem can be solved on a line-per-line basis so using arrays to hold the input and output is useless.

Here is your program, simplified. I also noted that `temp` was useless within the loop (though it was likely optimized out anyway, it polluted the code).

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    size_t number = 0;
    std::cin >> number;

    for(size_t i = 0 ; i < number; ++i)
    {
        size_t a = 0, n = 0;

        std::cin >> n;

        while (n)
        {
            n /= 5;
            a += n;
        }

        std::cout << a << '\n';
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do better ? Oh yes! The main issues here is that [the C++ streams are none too fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166263/how-to-get-iostream-to-perform-better) so you may get a good boost by switching to the C reading methods... however they are not as nice (and safe).

Comment: So, turns out that just using scanf and printf reduced the time to 0.2 seconds.Thank you.

Comment: @LakshayChhikara: Not surprised here, the IO Streams do not obey the C++ spirit of *you don't pay for what you don't need*.

Comment: @LakshayChhikara: no problem, it was a fun little piece of code to work with so I am actually grateful to you for posting it up :)