# Separated CIN input with NO separators

Tags: c++, input, cin

So, the question is as follows: I have an input data, loaded into cin, which (data) has no separators at all and consists of 2-dig. hex numbers, for ex:

```
ab2b6f //here it is ab 2b 6f
```

Is it possible to separate them without buffering? I do not want to waste a memory, 'cause inputs can be really long;

UPD: solved by using 2-char buffer.

===================================

Comment: cin::get or cin::read? you can have a 2 chars buffer and read into it in a loop. so you will waste(?) only 2 bytes.

Comment: @HayriUğurKoltuk, then manually convert chars into decimal ints? I do not need a hex value, a need a _decimal_ representation of each number in stream.

Comment: yes, does it make any problems in your case?

Comment: Nope, just to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set an input buffer as described here: [How to get IOStream to perform better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166263/how-to-get-iostream-to-perform-better) and then [`istream::read(...)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) an exact number of bytes from the stream.