# Fastest way to read a pipe from C/C++ program?

Tags: c++, linux, shell, unix, pipe

If I want to pipe bytes of data in to a C/C++ program on Linux like this:

> cat my_file | ./my_app

but:

1. We cannot assume the piped data is going to originate from a file
2. We wish to interpret the data as bytes in the file (as opposed to strings)

what would be the fastest technique to read the pipe from the C/C++ application?

I have done a little research and found:

- `read()`
- `std::cin.read()`
- `popen()`

but I am not sure if there is a better way, or which of the above would be better.

EDIT: There **is** a performance requirement on this, hence why I am asking for the technique with the smallest overhead.

Comment: Note `popen()` doesn't read anything from the pipe, but just gives you the necessary file descriptors you can use to call `read()`.

Comment: Not `popen()`. In C, use `read()`; in C++, probably `read()` again, but using `std::cin` would also work.

Comment: And why are you bothering about performance? Using the `|` in the shell and reading from `std::cin` would be fairly OK, flexible and robust.

Comment: FYI, `cat my_file | ./my_app` is slower than `./my_app <file`, and less flexible (you get a descriptor you can't `seek()` on). Why are you specifying it that way?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy simply my misunderstanding that there were two ways and one is faster...

Comment: Also, minimizing overhead and maximizing throughput are completely different goals. Please be specific about which one you care about.

Comment: If you *do* get a proper file descriptor on stdin, you might actually be better off mmap'ing it. If you *don't* get a real file descriptor, and your real goal is to minimize overhead, you'd use the `read()` syscall directly. If you *don't* get a real file descriptor, and your real goal is to maximize throughput, then you'll likely do well to use the buffered calls exposed by the standard library.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy what determines whether I get a proper file descriptor?

Comment: I meant a _seekable_ file descriptor. Which is to say, not attached to a pipeline or socket but directly to a file.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It sounds like read() would be better then. Could you suggest this in an answer and I will accept

Comment: **What is your application?** Why do you care that much about performance? Please edit the question to improve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Why do you care that much about performance?

1 gigabyte from `/dev/urandom` can be piped into `wc` in 1 minutes (and `wc` is running 15% of the time, waiting for data on the rest) ! Just try `time (head -1000000000c /dev/urandom|wc)`

But the fastest way would be to use the [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) syscall with a quite big buffer (e.g. 64Kbytes to 256Kbytes).

Of course, read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and carefully [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) related `man` pages.

**Study for inspiration the source code** of the [Linux kernel](https://kernel.org/), of [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), of [musl-libc](https://musl.libc.org/). They all are [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) projects, so feel free to **contribute to them** and to improve them.

But I bet that in practice using `popen`, or `stdin`, or reading from `std::cin` won't add much overhead.

You could also increase the *stdio* buffer with [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5166263/841108).

(If you read from *stdin* the file descriptor is `STDIN_FILENO` which is 0)

You might be interested by [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html), [vdso(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

You certainly should read documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report.

#### You could use [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) techniques to optimize performance.

Look into the [MILEPOST GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MILEPOST_GCC) and [Ctuning](https://ctuning.org/) projects. Consider joining the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) one. Read of course [*Understanding machine learning: From theory to algorithms*](https://www.cambridge.org/) ISBN 978-1-107-05713-5

Comment: May I ask, how would I get the file descriptor for the second parameter?

Comment: Sorry one last question- I am about to replace my std::cin.read() with the system call read() you suggested. However, I also have a while loop checking for !std::cin.eof() so that I grab all bytes. To see the full benefits of the read() system call is there a way I can replace the check for while(!std::cin.eof()) ?

Comment: I don't understand why you care that much about performance. But please read the man page of `read(2)`.  **What is your application?** Please edit your question to tell much more about it.

Comment: @user997112, don't mix buffered and unbuffered calls regarding the same file descriptor -- if you're using `read()` (which is unbuffered), you shouldn't be using **any** `std::cin` calls.

Answer (score 2):

When you pipe data in like that, the piped input *is* the standard input.  Just read from cin (or stdin) like a normal console program.

Just use `std::cin.read()`.  There's no reason to deal with `popen()` or its ilk.

---

Just to clarify... there is no pipe-specific way to read the input.  As far as your program is concerned, there's cin and that's it.

This question might help you out on the speed front though...
[Why is reading lines from stdin much slower in C++ than Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371238/why-is-reading-lines-from-stdin-much-slower-in-c-than-python)

Comment: This has to be written with high performance in mind- thats why I am asking what is the method with the smallest overhead?

Comment: Minimizing overhead is very situationally dependent -- sometimes standard-library-provided buffering helps things, sometimes it hurts. I don't know that you could get a generic answer that's always going to be right; you'd probably be better off benchmarking.

Comment: Besides using std::cin::read() what other possibilities do I have to benchmark against?

Comment: Well, `std::cin::read()` is the C++ way. There's also the C standard-library calls, and direct invocation of your OS syscalls. And your operating system and standard library will typically provide a lot of flags for tuning.

Comment: But unless you've already measured enough to know you have a problem, and you know it's the read process that's causing the problem, why are you here to start with? :)