# fscanf vs ifstream speed

Tags: c++, iostream, stdio

I conjectured that `ifstream` would be faster than `fscanf` because `fscanf` has to parse the format string every time it runs, whereas, with `ifstream`, we know at compile time what kind of "thing" we want to read.

But when I ran this quick and dirty benchmark

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

#define NUMBER_OF_NUMBERS 100000000

int nums[NUMBER_OF_NUMBERS];

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    FILE * fp = fopen("nums.txt","r");
    auto start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_NUMBERS; i++)
        fscanf(fp,"%d",nums+i);
    auto end = clock();
    fclose(fp);

    auto first = end - start;

    ifstream fin("nums.txt");
    start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_NUMBERS; i++)
        fin >> nums[i];
    end = clock();
    fin.close();

    auto second = end - start;

    cout << "CLOCKS_PER_SEC : " << CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
    cout << "first          : " << first << endl;
    cout << "first (sec)    : " << first / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds" << endl;
    cout << "second         : " << second << endl;
    cout << "second (sec)   : " << second / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds" << endl;
    cout << "diff           : " << second - first << endl;
    cout << "diff (sec)     : " << (second - first) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I got as output the following:

```
CLOCKS_PER_SEC : 1000000
first          : 12336249
first (sec)    : 12 seconds
second         : 25738587
second (sec)   : 25 seconds
diff           : 13402338
diff (sec)     : 13 seconds
```

`ifstream` is more than twice as slow as `fscanf`. Where does `fscanf` get all this speed?

EDIT:

I'm on a reasonably modern 64-bit intel mac, using command line tools that come with xcode, in case it is relevant at all.

Comment: Are you running an optimized build? \

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `g++ -Wall --std=c++11 test.cpp && ./a.out` is what i did originally, but I just tried again with `g++ -O3 -Wall --std=c++11 test.cpp && ./a.out` with similar results

Comment: Short answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166263/how-to-get-iostream-to-perform-better

Comment: @GregHewgill At least from a cursory look at that post, the accepted answer talks about console input. I would have imagined that the argument that "console speeds don't really matter" might not exactly apply when implementing file io. At the very least, I'm pretty sure `fscanf` above isn't using the `stdin` device

Comment: With constant formats, I've come across compilers that analyze the format at _compile_ time.  The basic `fscanf(fp,"%d",nums+i)` could be simplified then into some sort of `nums[i] = getint(fp)`.  Not saying that is what happened here - would need to inspect the assembly.

Comment: The marked duplicate has almost nothing to do with this question, since the other post is about the standard streams, rather than `fstream`s. Nor is it the best post about the standard streams.

Comment: What happens if you swap the order of the two tests?

Answer (score -2):

`fscanf` does not need to parse the format string at all.  It uses a greedy algorithm that looks for the `'%'` character and then uses a simple switch statement to generate the input.  `ifstream` on the other hand, needs to perform lookups on its vtable to determine how each minute detail of the input is used.

All this being said, `fscanf` cannot be extended without altering the C library, while `ifstream` is as easy as sub-classing it.

EDIT:
All of this is also part of the fact that C's `fscanf` library routine has had far more time/work put into it and more opportunities for optimization.  The C++ library is only arbitrary consequence of the C++ standard and thus has not had the same scrutiny applied to it.

Comment: `It uses a greedy algorithm that looks for the '%' character and then uses a simple switch statement to generate the input.` If that's not "parsing" then I don't know what is. And I don't see where a virtual table comes into it; streams deal with their insertion operands through basic function overloading.

Comment: Does `ifstream` still need to consult its vtable even if I have instantiated on the stack? I thought virtual methods were only relevant when I was accessing through pointers, where the exact underlying type is unknown at compile time

Comment: Not the vtable of the things being printed, but the `ifstream`'s own vtable.  Because `ifstream` can be sub-classed (and thus a different set of vtable entries) it has to perform the lookup.

Comment: @randomusername: That's.. nonsense. This is implementation-defined but at least in libstdc++ `ifstream` isn't even polymorphic: it doesn't _have_ a virtual table (though its member `basic_filebuf` instantiation does). [Here's the source if you don't believe me](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a00881_source.html) (and this is why typical advice is _not_ to derive from standard containers or stream types)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Please, sir high and mighty, grace us with the true answer then...

Comment: @randomusername: Just because you are wrong is not a good reason to call me names