# Optimizing OBJ file parser in c++

Tags: c++, parsing, opengl

I wrote an OBJ file parser in c++ and it works. It can load any OBJ file into a model. However it is incredibly slow. Loading one low-poly model can take up to ten seconds. Is there any way to optimize this or is my computer just extremeley low? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
RawModel OBJLoader::loadModel(const std::string& filePath, Loader* loader)
{
    std::ifstream file(filePath);

    std::vector<glm::vec3> positions;
    std::vector<glm::vec2> uvs;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> normals;

    std::vector<unsigned int> indices;

    float* positionsArray = nullptr;
    float* uvsArray = nullptr;
    float* normalsArray = nullptr;
    unsigned int* indicesArray = nullptr;

    bool firstFace = true;

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
    std::vector<std::string> currentLine = split(line, ' ');

    if (line[0] == 'v' && line[1] == ' ')
    {
    glm::vec3 pos(parseFloat(currentLine[1]), parseFloat(currentLine[2]), parseFloat(currentLine[3]));
    positions.push_back(pos);
    }
    else if (line[0] == 'v'  && line[1] == 't')
    {
    glm::vec2 uv(parseFloat(currentLine[1]), parseFloat(currentLine[2]));
    uvs.push_back(uv);
    }
    else if (line[0] == 'v'  && line[1] == 'n')
    {
    glm::vec3 norm(parseFloat(currentLine[1]), parseFloat(currentLine[2]), parseFloat(currentLine[3]));
    normals.push_back(norm);
    }
    else if (line[0] == 'f'  && line[1] == ' ')
    {
    if (firstFace)
    {
    uvsArray = new float[positions.size() * 2];
    normalsArray = new float[positions.size() * 3];
    firstFace = false;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> vert1 = split(currentLine[1], '/');
    std::vector<std::string> vert2 = split(currentLine[2], '/');
    std::vector<std::string> vert3 = split(currentLine[3], '/');

    processVertex(vert1, &indices, uvs, normals, uvsArray, normalsArray);
    processVertex(vert2, &indices, uvs, normals, uvsArray, normalsArray);
    processVertex(vert3, &indices, uvs, normals, uvsArray, normalsArray);
    }
    }

    positionsArray = new float[positions.size() * 3];
    indicesArray = new unsigned int[indices.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++)
    {
    positionsArray[i*3] = positions[i].x;
    positionsArray[i*3+1] = positions[i].y;
    positionsArray[i*3+2] = positions[i].z;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < indices.size(); i++) indicesArray[i] = indices[i];

    return loader->loadToVao(positionsArray, positions.size() * 3, indicesArray, indices.size(), uvsArray,positions.size()*2);
}

float parseFloat(const std::string& str)
{
return std::stof(str);
}

int parseInt(const std::string& str)
{
return std::stoi(str);
}

void  processVertex(std::vector<std::string> vertData, std::vector<unsigned         int>* indices, std::vector<glm::vec2> uvs, std::vector<glm::vec3> normals,
float* uvsArray, float* normalsArray)
{
unsigned int currentVertexPointer = parseInt(vertData[0]) - 1;
indices->push_back(currentVertexPointer);

glm::vec2 currentUv = uvs[parseInt(vertData[1]) - 1];
uvsArray[currentVertexPointer * 2] = currentUv.x;
uvsArray[currentVertexPointer * 2 + 1] = 1 - currentUv.y;

glm::vec3 currentNorm = normals[parseInt(vertData[2]) - 1];
normalsArray[currentVertexPointer * 3] = currentNorm.x;
normalsArray[currentVertexPointer * 3+1] = currentNorm.y;
normalsArray[currentVertexPointer * 3+2] = currentNorm.z;
}

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &str, const char &delim)
{
typedef std::string::const_iterator iter;
iter beg = str.begin();
std::vector<std::string> tokens;

while (beg != str.end()) {
//cout << ":" << beg._Myptr << ":" << endl;
iter temp = find(beg, str.end(), delim);
if (beg != str.end())
tokens.push_back(std::string(beg, temp));
beg = temp;
while ((beg != str.end()) && (*beg == delim))
beg++;
}

return tokens;
}
```

Comment: There are lots of OBJ readers out there. Check one out and figure that out yourself. This is more of a software reviewing question rather than a programming problem.

Comment: I recommend clarifying OBJ because on windows systems, the intermediate file (after compiling) is usually "*.obj", often called an OBJ file.

Comment: Take a look at "tinyobjloader", I use it a lot and it seems to have a good performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, obvious improvements:

- Pass vector `vertData` to `processVertex` by (const) reference.
- Reuse one vector where possible by `clear`ing it
- Rewrite `split` to take vector by reference as argument, and write to this vector instead of return value

Second, forget about first, and use profiler. For example, [gprof](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/) on linux, or [sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy) on windows.

Comment: Additionally, you can try to speed up the std:ifstream. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166263/how-to-get-iostream-to-perform-better

Comment: You will also gain performance when you pre-allocate (vector::resize) the vectors storage. Otherwise your data will be copied around multiple times