# Python: efficient file io

Tags: python, file-io

What is the most efficient (fastest) way to simultaneously read in two large files and do some processing?

I have two files; a.txt and b.txt, each containing about a hundred thousand corresponding lines. My goal is to read in the two files and then do some processing on each line pair

```
def kernel:
    a_file=open('a.txt','r')
    b_file=open('b.txt', 'r')
    a_line = a_file.readline()
    b_line = b_file.readline()
    while a_line:
        process(a_spl,b_spl) #process requiring both corresponding file lines
```

I looked in to xreadlines and readlines but i'm wondering if i can do better. speed is of paramount importance for this task.

thank you.

Comment: Python isn't great for speed. C or C++ is recommended. Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164538/how-can-i-speed-up-line-by-line-reading-of-an-ascii-file-c

Comment: @Alvin K.: Profile first: Python is still fast enough to be able to outstrip *most* forms of I/O, especially if said I/O is hitting disk or network.

Comment: @Thanatos: profiling is also mentioned in the link above, which claims that I/O isn't the main bottleneck. Thanks for highlighting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code does not accumulate data from the input files in memory, unless the `process` function does that by itself.

```
from itertools import izip

def process(line1, line2):
  # process a line from each input

with open(file1, 'r') as f1:
  with open(file2, 'r') as f2:
    for a, b in izip(f1, f2):
      process(a, b)
```

If the `process` function is efficient, this code should run quickly enough for most purposes.  The `for` loop will terminate when the end of **one** of the files is reached.  If either file contains an extraordinarily long line (i.e. XML, JSON), or if the files are not text, this code may not work well.

Comment: You forgot to mention that your file **requires `itertools` module**. Without the following it won't work: `from itertools import izip`.

Comment: so how can you explicitly close it if you don't give it a handle?

Comment: Edited to address both comments above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `with` statement to make sure your files are closed after the execution. From [this blog entry](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm):

> to open a file, process its contents, and make sure to close it, you can simply do:

```
with open("x.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
    do something with data
```

Answer (score 1):

String IO can be pretty fast -- probably your processing will be what slows things down. Consider a simple input loop to feed a queue like:

```
queue = multiprocessing.Queue(100)
a_file = open('a.txt')
b_file = open('b.txt')
for pair in itertools.izip(a_file, b_file):
     queue.put(pair) # blocks here on full queue
```

You can set up a pool of processes pulling items from the queue and taking action on each, assuming your problem can be parallelised this way.

Comment: In Python 2.x, be sure to use *itertools.izip()* so that the zip step doesn't happen all at once and pull both files completely into memory.

Comment: maybe so, i'm reading in a list of tokens at each step and storing it in a list. maybe that's the bottleneck. program is hogging memory.

Comment: Thanks Raymond for picking up that glaring mistake. Absolutely use izip in this scenario, not zip. I've fixed the example.

Comment: thanks for the advice. got it to work using izip. also resolved my memory issue. did some optimizations on the algorithm and reduced the space consumption.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change your while condition to the following so that it doesn't fail when a has more lines than b.

```
while a_line and b_line
```

Otherwise, that looks good. You are reading in the two lines that you need, then processing. You could even multithread this by reading in `N` pairs of line and sending each pair off to a new thread or similar.

Comment: we are sure it will be the same line. goal is to reduce r.t. so avoided extra check

Comment: Your program will crash horribly when you least expect it. If you have a GOOD REASON to be that worried about cycles, switch to C.

Comment: zip will stop at the shorter of the two files